# Where is the database saved, using the cellphone emulator?

Tags: android, database, android-emulator

I hope this doesnt break the site's rules:

My question is what i posted in the title:

If i use the ROOM functions in Android Studio and then test my app on a cell phone emulator, where on my computer, is the database stored?

Comment: what is `ROOM functions in Android Studio`

Answer (score 3):

Inside your, Android Studio go to Device File Explorer

Then go to data->data->AppPackageName->your_db

Then right-click and extract or save it to your PC and then you can view it and also perform Query using some [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

[image]